# Swift Save viewcontroller state using coder beyond app close

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, nscoder

I am using Xcode 8 and swift 2.3

I want to save the entire view controller to file and restore state even after app closes.
I searched everywhere and found we need to use coder for that. but all just shows to save an object.
but here I need to save entire ViewContoller and subviews.

ViewCotroller will have three buttons

- Add Text
- Add Image : User can add any number of textViews and Images. So I need to save all that info also.
- Add ViewController : User may have an array of this viewController and need to save all.

**Question 1)**

Can just save self.view and can it save all subviews automatically ?

**Question 2)**

I need to init without coder at start by just using

```
let nameVccVar = nameVcc()
```

and

```
let nameVccVar = nameVcc(coder: CodeVar)
```

**Question 3)**

How do I save all this coded data to file using NSKeyedUnarchiver and retrieve back?

Kindly help me or give me tips to make all this work

```
class nameVcc: UIViewController
{
    var nameIntVar = 0
    var nameStringVar = "Save this"
    var nameImageVar = UIImage()

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    required init?(coder NkdPsgVar: NSCoder)
    {
        super.init(coder: NkdPsgVar)
    }

    override func encodeWithCoder(DkdPsgVar: NSCoder)
    {

    }

    func addTextViewBtnClick()
    {
        let viewVar = UIView()

        // Set many values for view 

        self.view.addSubview(viewVar)
    }

    func addImageViewBtnClick()
    {
        let imgViewVar = UIImageView()

        // Set many values for ImageView

        self.view.addSubview(imgViewVar)
    }
}
```

I also tired :

```
convenience init()
{
    self.init()
}
```

and

```
convenience init()
{
    self.init(coder: NSCoder())
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR:**
There are key steps and methods required to implement state restoration in your app.

1. Opting-in for App State Restoration in App Delegate by returning `true` for these methods `shouldSaveApplicationState` and `shouldRestoreApplicationState`.
2. Setting **Restoration Identifier** for view controllers that you want state restoration implemented in.
3. Implementing `encodeRestorableStateWithCoder` and `decodeRestorableStateWithCoder` methods in your view controller. The former is used to save any state information of your view controller to disk using `encodeObjectForKey` method. The latter shall be used to restore the state back from your saved contents to the disk by using `decodeObjectForKey` method.

Watch this awesome blog post about [State Restoration](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/state-preservation-and-restoration/) for easier grasp. If you have time, also do spend on watching [State Restoration WWDC Session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2012/208/).

---

There is **no need** to save your entire `ViewController` yourself. `UIKit` does that for you when you set your Restoration Identifier (**In Interface Builder**). The only thing we need to focus for state restoration is to save your essential **properties** needed to re-create your app's **"State"**, for example, a `Bool` property which determines whether you want to display a specific button or not.

**Now coming to your series of questions....**

> Can I just save self.view and can it save all subviews automatically ?

You do not need to save any of your views. All subviews will be handled by `UIKit`. Encode your required properties (such as **Bool** flags, **count** variables, **key properties** that can be used to fetch data from api call for your datasource etc.) inside `encodeRestorableStateWithCoder` method. Don't forget to re-contruct your view controller's state from `decodeRestorableStateWithCoder`. Both of these methods belond to `UIStateRestoring` protocol.

> I need to init without coder at start by just using

No need to do any fancy inits.

> How do I save all this coded data to file using NSKeyedUnarchiver and
>   retrieve back?

As I said earlier, implement necessary `UIStateRestoring` protocol methods to save and restore your app's state.

Comment: All the links you have mentioned shows c coding... Is there any swift version of the same ?

Comment: Here is Ray Wenderlich: https://www.raywenderlich.com/117471/state-restoration-tutorial

Comment: How do I call encodeRestorableStateWithCoder and decodeRestorableStateWithCoder on button click.

Comment: You do not need to call it. It will be automatically called (`encodeRestorableStateWithCoder`) when the the app goes to background state. When you open your app back up, `decodeRestorableStateWithCoder ` will be called.

Comment: No that's not my case. I have explained as another question. Can you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46398956/swift-store-and-restore-viewcontroller-state-on-button-click